# Display mysqli result multiple times

Tags: php, mysqli

I asked this recently but it got marked as duplicate and deleted.
Please look at my question before marking it down because it is not the same and I am struggling to figure this out.

I want to echo the 'company' and 'area' results from a MYSQLI query into my page, at separate points in the body of a php page.

Only the first echo will show. Please show my mistake.

```
<?php 

$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= "/Connections/****";
include_once($path);

$dbhandle=mysqli_connect($hostname_Demo, $username_Demo, $password_Demo, $database_Demo);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql_RS1="SELECT * from CompanyName where area = 1";
$result=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql_RS1);

?>

<head>
<title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo $row['company'];
}
?>

<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo $row['area'];
}
?>

<?php  $dbhandle->close();  ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is what I ended with. It works so I hope it is correct. Thanks for everyones help.

```
$sql_RS1="SELECT * from CompanyName where area = 1";
$result=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql_RS1);
$row =array();
while ($x= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  $row_RS1=$x;
?>

<?php
$sql_RS2="SELECT * from employees where EmployeeID = 79";
$result=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql_RS2);
$row_RS2 =array();
while ($x= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  $row_RS2=$x;
?>

<head>
<title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>
<?php  echo $row_RS1['company']; ?>
</p>
<p>
<?php  echo $row_RS1['company']; ?>
</p>
<p>
<?php  echo $row_RS1['area']; ?>
</p>
<p>
<?php  echo $row_RS2['EmployeeID'];  ?>
</p>
<p>
<?php  echo $row_RS2['Surname']; ?>
</p>
<p>
<?php  echo $row_RS2['EmployeeID'];  ?>
</p>
<p>
<?php  $dbhandle->close();  ?>
</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code

```
<?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    $data_array[] = $row;
    }

    foreach ($data_array as $data) {
        echo $data['company'];
    }
    foreach ($data_array as $data) {
        echo $data['area'];
    }
```

Do like this with.., You don't want to have to make more queries to your database.

Comment: Thanks I tried this and got somewhere. But I will have multiple queries on the same page. How do I do this with multiple queries please?

Comment: Multiple queries means? Are you getting records from another table?

Comment: Yes. Problem solved, please see answer below and thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You are fetching same row two different which is not correct.

Something like this should work

```
<?php 
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= "/Connections/****";
include_once($path);

$dbhandle=mysqli_connect($hostname_Demo, $username_Demo, $password_Demo, $database_Demo);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql_RS1="SELECT * from CompanyName where area = 1";
$result=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql_RS1);
$row =array();
while ($x= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
      $row[]=$x;
$i=0;
?>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
   echo $row[i]['company'];
?>

<?php
   echo $row[i]['area'];
   $i++;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham. I worked with your suggestion to come to the conclusion below, which works. I think what I was asking was quite basic. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score -2):

try merging them it looks like they are just the same

```html
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo  $row['company']." 
".$row['area'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to split the results into different parts of the page.